# Class like simply Vector in C#

Tags: c#, class, vector

I need to write a simple class.
I need 2 methods:

```
Vector property = new Vector();
property.add("key", "value"); //set value of key
property.get("key"); //return value of key
```

Does CSharp have a class like that?

I'm trying write my own class

```
string[] keys;

public void add(string key, string value)
{
 this.keys[key] = value;
}
```

but string can not be index of array(but must).

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`. Not sure why you call this "vector".

Comment: Yes, but Dictionary don't have method like get. I need that(because is simply)

Comment: @SeCorp Of course [it does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.90).aspx). Of what use could it be without it?

Comment: @SeCorp Don't write `Resolved` at the top of your question, instead you need to mark one of the answers below as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) to do this. You may also define `Vector` as a class of  `Dictionary` if you would like to use `Vector` as a `Dictionary`

**Example**

```
class Vector : Dictionary<string,string>
{
    public string Get(string Key) //Create a new void Get(string Key) which returns a particular value from a specific Key in the Dictionary (Vector)
    {
        return this[Key]; //Return the key from the Dictionary
    }
    public void add(string Key, string Value) //Create a new void Add(string Key, string Value) which creates a particular value referring to a specific Key in the Dictionary (Vector)
    {
        this.Add(Key, Value); //Add the key and its value to Vector
    }
}

Vector property = new Vector(); //Initialize a new class Vector of name property
property.add("key", "value"); //Sets a key of name "key" and its value "value" of type stirng
MessageBox.Show(property.Get("key")); //Returns "value"
//MessageBox.Show(property["key"]); //Returns "value"
```

This will create a new class `Vector` which implements `Dictionary` so that you'll be able to use `Vector` as a `Dictionary`.

**Notice**: The [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) is a generic class providing a mapping from a set of keys to a set of values. Each addition to the dictionary consists of a value and its associated key. Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast because the [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class is implemented as a hash table.

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: To add: That is a bit unnecessary. He only used the "Vector" to describe what he tried to accomplish but doesn't really need vectors. The dictionary itself has all the purpose he needs (store something to be accessed with a key).

Answer (score 3):

```
Vector property = new Vector();  -->   var property = new Dictionary<string, string>();
property.add("key", "value");    -->   property.Add("key", "value");
property.get("key")              -->   property["key"]
```

**Exception handling:**
The last one could throw an exception if the key is not found in the dictionary. An alternative way which never throws is:

```
string value;
bool keyFound = property.TryGetValue("key", out value);
```

**Terminology:** What you have in mind is normally called a *dictionary* or *map*; the term *vector*, being the opposite of *scalar*, is usually reserved for a simple array or list of values.

---

**P.S.:** You can create your own class (see below) — though why you reject `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` simply because the relevant methods aren't named `add` and `get` is beyond me.

```
class PropertyMap
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public string add(string key, string value) { map.Add(key, value); }
    public string @get(string key) { return map[key]; }

    public string this[string key]  //  <-- indexer allows you to access by string
    {
        get
        {
            return @get(key);
        }
        set
        {
            add(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, i don't know that I cann get acces by that way. PS. Vector(is pseudocode, I wanted to show You what I nedd).

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use a Dictionary for that.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("Key", "Value");

//access using:
dict["Key"];
```

Edit:
If you want, you can also use the dictionary for other objects not only strings. If your "values" are actually numbers, you can also go with:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, double>();
```

, which might save you some conversions back to numbers.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, i don't know that I cann get acces by that way!

Comment: In many ways the dictionary would lose all its purpose if you coudln't!

Answer (score 2):

use this code ...

```
private Dictionary<string, string> keys = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public void add(string key, string value)
{
    this.keys.Add(key, value);
}

public string get(string key)
{
    return this.keys[key];
}
```